# Subset matrix with arrays in r

Tags: r, matrix, subset

It is probably fairly basic but I have not found an easy solution.

Assume I have a three-dimensional matrix:

```
m <- array(seq_len(18),dim=c(3,3,2))
```

and I would like to subset the matrix with the arrays of indexes:

```
idxrows <- c(1,2,3)
idxcols <- c(1,1,2)
```

obtaining the arrays in position `(1,1)`,`(2,1)` and `(3,2)`, that is:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]   10   14   18
```

I have tried `m[idxrows,idxcols,]` but without any luck.

Is there anyway to do it (without obviously using a for loop)?

Comment: arguably using loops, at least for quick application is also an option, and easy to generalize: `x <- integer(0L)`
`for (i in 1:length(idxrows)) {x[i] <- m[idxrows[i], idxcols[i]]}`

Comment: The results is the same as using:
`cbind(m[idxrows[1],idxcols[1],],
      m[idxrows[2],idxcols[2],],
      m[idxrows[3],idxcols[3],])`

Comment: Maybe you have a typo. Should idxcols be c(1,2,3)? You can obtain your desired output by rbinding the diagonals of z-dimetnional matrix in the array: `rbind(diag(m[,,1]), diag(m[,,2]))`.

Comment: `mapply` and `lapply` are all loops, but for a different voice `sapply(seq_along(idxrows), function(i) m[idxrows[i], idxcols[i],])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is any easy built in *extract* syntax, but you can work around this with `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(i, j) m[i,j,], idxrows, idxcols)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    6
#[2,]   10   11   15
```

---

Or slightly more convoluted, create a index matrix whose columns match the dimensions of the original array:

```
thirdDim <- dim(m)[3]
index <- cbind(rep(idxrows, each = thirdDim), rep(idxcols, each = thirdDim), 1:thirdDim)
matrix(m[index], nrow = thirdDim)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    6
#[2,]   10   11   15
```